# Logging WebApp outputs to BlobStorage $logs not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

My scenario:

- Created a default .NET CORE 6 app razor pages app and amended the homepage get:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
     private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

     public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     public void OnGet()
     {
        _logger.LogError("DING DONG");
         throw new Exception("We really FooBarred this one!\r\n");
     }
}
```

- Published it to an Azure free tier app service
- Turned on `App Service Logs > Application Logging (Blob) - Level Verbose`
- Assigned it to the `$logs` folder in the blob storage (which exists in same region)

But the logs are not populated. When I check the live log stream, my errors show up fine.

I then tried:

- the same thing with a CORE 3.1 app
- adding `builder.Logging.ClearProviders().AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();`

I went to `Diagnostic settings` and turned on a whole bunch of app logging, which all gets logged fine in the blob storage under their own respective folders... except for the errors!

**But why are my $logs not recording?** - The few tutorials I found all say I've done the right thing but I can't see anything in that blobstorage logs folder!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so many different things but could not get my logs going to the default "$logs" container.

In the end, all I had to do was create my own container "custom-logs" in the blobstorage service and assign my logs to dump there instead!